# Why does my regex work in a tester but not in re.search?

Tags: python, regex

Essentially I want to strip out the text in-between a closing square bracket "]" and the start of a word (CALL or RETURN)

Strings to work with:

`[2018-01-18 18:22:28,516] .- CALL do.something(key=True)`

`[2018-01-18 18:22:28,517] .- RETURN do.something`

Expected output:

`.-`
`.-`

My code looks something like this:

```
def find_middle_bit(string):
    string_of_interest = re.search(r"\](.*)[^A-Za-z]", string)
    print str(string.strip())
    if string_of_interest:
        print string_of_interest.group(1)


line = "[2018-01-18 18:22:28,516] .- CALL do.something(key=True)"
find_middle_bit(line)
```

Actual output:

`.- CALL do.something(key=True`

What am I missing here?

Comment: `[^A-Za-z]` is "not alphabetic". why would that work?

Comment: Your `(.*)` is greedy - it'll match as many characters as it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use lookarounds to target the text you want to capture:

```
string = "[2018-01-18 18:22:28,516] .- CALL do.something(key=True)"
string_of_interest = re.search(r"(?<=\]\s)(.*?)(?=\s(?:CALL|RETURN))", string)
print str(string.strip())
if string_of_interest:
    print string_of_interest.group(1)

.-          <-- (this is what gets printed)
```

### Demo

Comment: Shouldn't the `.*` be ungreedy ?

Comment: @Faibbus Yes, it should be.  I didn't notice because I only tested without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use instead:

```
\]([^A-Z]*)
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N6h4Zj/1/)

Your regex `\](.*)[^A-Za-z]` matches first a closing bracket `]` (that's OK) and then some number of anychar followed by one char that is non letter. Because `.*` is greedy, it takes as many chars, as possible. In your case it reaches end of the string and then backracks once to match `)` with `[^A-Za-z]`

Answer (score 0):

I tend to find using group matching to be pretty helpful for this sort of work.  Requires less brain power.  Consider:

```
from functools import partial
import re

lines = ['[2018-01-18 18:22:28,516] .- CALL do.something(key=True)', 
         '[2018-01-18 18:22:28,517] .- RETURN do.something']
extract = partial(re.sub, '\[.*?\]\s*(.*?)\s.*', '\g<1>')
for line in lines:
   print(extract(line))
```

#### output

```
.-
.-
```